# How can I compare randomness with flipping and spinning a coin?

Tags: probability

When I flip a coin, I don't feel the experiment is truly random. The initial case may have a strong influence on the final output but this is not the case with spinning the coin vertically. My question is is it true that spinning a coin will be more random in comparison with flipping it? If so, how one can prove this test? If not, what is wrong with the preceding logic?

Comment: There is a section in statistics named hypothesis testing. U make a hypothesis about a statistic function (like the mean value in ur case) and u check what is the probability of ur hypothesis being correct or wrong. So u will never be 100% sure.

Comment: "When I flip a coin, I don't feel the experiment is truly random." What is your definition of "truly random"? Equal probability? But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persi Diaconis has studied exactly this problem. A nice introduction to his work can be found in [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYnJv68T3MM). It addresses exactly the questions you have.

Also see [this related video, also by Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obg7JPd6cmw). There he explains that spinning is significantly worse than throwing.

Answer (score 0):

Since u are performing a coin toss the $X=$ number of heads, $X\sim Bion(p)$ if the toss was fair  then $p=1/2$ but since it's not (as u suspect), you will have to make a hypothesis like $p\neq 1/2$. Now for doing ur test i would suggest using the central limit theorem, in order to use it tho u will have to spin over 30 coins for the test (i suggest 100).
After that u have to calculate the quantity $Z_n(p)=\frac {X-np}{\sqrt {np(1-p)}}\sim N(0,1)$. $P(Z_n(p))=a$ u can check the a score for $p=1/2$  [[here]](http://images.tutorvista.com/cms/images/67/full-Z-score-table.PNG) and see what is the propability of this beign true